# Puzzle about $4$-tuples less than $(x,x,x,x)$

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Let $X$ be a $4$-tuple of matching entries, so $X = (x, x, x, x)$. Let $C$ be a collection of $4$-tuples such that $(a,b,c,d) \in C \implies a+b+c+d \leq 4x$ where $X$ must be an element of $C$, and no two $4$-tuples in $C$ have the same $a$,$b$,$c$, or $d$ value.

Let $f(X)$ be defined as the maximum possible cardinality of $C$. How would you find a closed form expression for $f(X)$?

So for example, if $X = (10,10,10,10)$, a possible maximal set $C$ would be

$$C = \{ (10,10,10,10),
       (1,13,13,13), 
       (13,1,12,12), 
       (12,12,1,11),
       (11,11,11,1),
       (2,9,9,9),\\
       (9,2,8,8),
       (8,8,2,7),
       (7,7,7,2),
       (3,6,6,6),
       (6,3,5,5),
       (5,5,3,4),
       (4,4,4,3) \}\;,$$

where $|C| = 13$.

Comment: This is my first post, any feedback on wording / formatting would be appreciated.  I suspect the answer is something like f(x) = (4x-1)/3, perhaps with some ugly floors and ceilings, but I'd need some proof that the greedy example for C I've provided actually gives a C of maximum cardinality.

Comment: You should include your own thoughts at solving this in your post. Since you are a new user and your question sounds like an exercise that has been given to you, this post reads like "I don't want to do my homework. Do it for me."

Comment: I actually constructed this question after playing a video game that ranks players by four individual stats, then calculates an overall ranking.  So this problem answers what the worst case overall ranking is for a player with balanced individual ranks.  It's just for fun. (Is there a tag for that?)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the C you provided is *not* of maximum cardinality. Couldn't I replace $(9, 2, 8, 8)$ with $(9, 14, 8, 8)$, replace $(8, 8, 2, 7)$ with $(8, 8, 14, 7)$, and then insert $(14, 2, 2, 14)$? That would bump the cardinality up to 14.

Comment: Yeah! You're right its not max cardinality.